# MySQL select item from several categories returns no results

Tags: mysql, left-join, categories, relational-division

I have this SQL-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name 
FROM cars c LEFT JOIN 
     _rel_cars_categories rcc ON c.id=rcc.car_id 
WHERE (rcc.category_id=33 AND rcc.category_id=51) 
  AND c.status >=10
```

The tables:

[image]

Unfortunally, it returns 0 results. When I replace AND whith OR, it works fine, but I want to get all that ar in both of these categories. It also can be 3, 4, 5... categories. How can I get the right result?

Comment: IN(x,y) GROUP BY n HAVING COUNT(*) = 2; Also, that's an INNER JOIN

Comment: I added the [tag:relational-division] tag. Follow that tag for description of this type of query and the solutions.

Comment: @Strawberry: can you express Raging Bull's query using INNER JOIN and not 'IN(x,y) GROUP BY n HAVING COUNT(*) = 2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select cars which have both 33 and 51 as category_id, try this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM cars c JOIN 
     _rel_cars_categories rcc ON c.id=rcc.car_id 
WHERE rcc.category_id IN (33,51) AND c.status >=10
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING count( distinct rcc.category_id ) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `WHERE (rcc.category_id=33 AND rcc.category_id=51)`.

Obviously a category can only be 33 OR 51. What you're looking for is likely to be `WHERE ID IN (33,51)` which will then return a match for any of the provided values.

So your final query should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name 
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN _rel_cars_categories rcc ON c.id=rcc.car_id 
WHERE rcc.category_id IN (33,51) AND c.status >=10
```

Comment: FYI, OP says: When I replace AND whith OR, it works fine. but I want to get **all** that are in both of these categories.